# Checking if Bluetooth is Disabled on iOS 5 without BluetoothManager

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, gamekit, core-bluetooth

I have seen that in iOS 5, CoreBluetooth provides the capability to check if Bluetooth is disabled. From what I have seen of the documentation, it is clearly aimed at bluetooth peripheral use. However, I am attempting to check if bluetooth is on because I am using GameKit (`GKPeerPickerController`) that will search endlessly for bluetooth connections if it is not enabled, which is an issue.

I tried to do this like so:

```
CBCentralManager * manager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] init];

if (manager.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn ) {

      //go ahead with GameKit
}
```

This does not work, and `manager.state` is always equal to null. What am I doing wrong here? Or alternatively, are there better ways to check the status of bluetooth on the iPhone?

EDIT: I don't want to call any private APIs because I will be submitting this app to the app store. I have edited my question title to clarify this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I discovered that by doing this:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];
NSMutableArray * discoveredPeripherals = [NSMutableArray new];
CBCentralManager * manager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
[manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:discoveredPeripherals options:options];
[manager stopScan];
```

If bluetooth is off, the system will pop up an alert view which will offer the choice to turn bluetooth on. Otherwise, if it finds a peripheral it will call a corresponding delegate method, but if there is nothing in that implementation you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: This only works on iphone 4S and above, and iPad3 and above (does NOT work on any iPod Touch, iPad1, iPad2, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer of your question by this [link](http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=2827). Check it out.

**Edited**

Have you checked out the [Game Kit Framework reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/GameKit_Collection.pdf)?

According to Apple:

> Game Kit offers your applications the ability to create Bluetooth
>   connections between two devices.

**Edited**

Then try this project. `https://github.com/sergiomtzlosa/MultiContactsSelector-ios`

Comment: That is a private API no? I don't think Apple will allow that in the App Store.

Comment: I have, as I stated in my question I am successfully using GameKit to create Bluetooth connections. However, the issue is that GameKit attempts to connect regardless of bluetooth being on or off, so I need to check its status.

Comment: Thank you for that link, it includes some functionality that will pop up an alert view when bluetooth is disabled and give you the option to change it, but I can't figure out where or how that was done. It seems like something that the system does, because that code does not generate any alert views or anything like that.